# See previous versions of an extension published to the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: chrome-web-store

The first version of my extension that I published to the Chrome Web Store was not 1 or 0.1 as initially users were manually installing it. How can I find out which was the first version that was published to the store?

I can't see previous versions in the developer dashboard. "Stats" shows installs over time but not which version they were.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of published versions for an extension on https://chrome-stats.com/. Just search for the extension and click on the Download tab. It should have all versions within the past 2 years.